# Calculate the InfluxDB average

Tags: influxdb

I want to process the value from InfluxDB on Grafana.
The final demand is to show how many miles the current vehicle has traveled in a certain time frame.
You can use the formula: average velocity * time.
Do the seniors have any good methods?
So what I'm thinking is: I've got the mean function for the average speed over a fixed period of time and the corresponding mileage, and then I want to add all the mileage together. How do I do that?
What if you only use SQL?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.) InfluxDB uses InfluxQL, not a SQL

2.) Your approach `average velocity * time` is innacurate

3.) Use suitable [InfluxDB functions](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/), I would say `INTEGRAL()` is the best function for this case + some basic arithmetic. Don't expect the 100% accuracy. Accuracy depends heavily on the metric sampling, e.g. 1 minute sampling - but what if vehicle is driving 59 seconds and it is not moving for that second when sampling is happening. So don't be supprised, when even 10 sec sampling will be inacurrate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!The formula has been determined, so I can do the calculation based on the formula. I finally solved this problem, using the Transorm feature on Dashboard

Comment: @sirmoner  I would say not a good idea. Grafana transformations are calculated in the browser, so it may work fine for small dataset, but it may kill the browser with big dataset (e. g. user can select anytime 1year time range with 10 sec granularity).